# Identify a role-playing poem about an artifact

Tags: product-identification, role-playing-poem

My Google-fu is rusty and I can't find this RPG poem<sup>[1]</sup> about making up stories about an artifact. Unfortunately since RPG poems are so short, there isn't much to say about them. Fortunately, if you know the poem I'm talking about, you should be able to figure it out immediately.

- Players are archaeologists, or are otherwise experts in their chosen fields
- A random item is chosen to be the artifact
- The point of the game is to make up stories about what the artifact might be
- A mechanic involved holding up a finger to make your point
- I think it was on [Norwegian Style](https://norwegianstyle.wordpress.com/) but I can't find it

---

<sup>1. [“Short, often LARP-like games designed to be played in 15 minutes. They often focus on a specific experience, rather than character or narrative.”](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/RPG_Glossary) For examples of Role-playing poems, have a look at [these poems](https://norwegianstyle.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/identity-poems/) on Norwegian style.</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the first I've ever heard about Role Playing Poems!  But your answer appears to be ["Orcology" by TomasHVM](https://web.archive.org/web/20191222144125/http://www.story-games.com/forums/discussion/comment/147919/#Comment_147919), which I found at Story Games.

It has the conditions you describe:

- The players are experts in the field of "orcology," a made-up scientific discipline.
- The game object is the players' newest find, which will revolutionize orcology.
- Ordinarily, every statement the players make about the object is to be treated as true, but once per game each player can raise an index finger to indicate that the last thing said was false; they then become the expert on that particular subject and have the final word for it.